# What is the punishment for those who discriminate on basis of birth?

Tags: dharma-shastras

Is there any punishment in Sanatan Dharma for those who discriminate on basis of birth. By discrimination, I mean depriving someone of some basic rights like education, drinking water from public water body, entering a temple etc. merely on basis of birth.

Comment: what is the punishment for those who discriminate on basis of guna?